# How to set state with React Hooks from outside an effect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**how do I set loading (returned by the upper scope function) so I can use it in component.js?** (see comment in code)

**controller.js**

```
const controller = {
    postRender: () => {
        const otherVar = useState(0);
        const loading = useState(false);
        
        useEffect(() => {
            // this is automatically called on every render and in fact accepts variables from postRender() scope
            otherVar(1);
        }, [other_var])

        const setLoading = (isLoaded) => {
            // this is called in component.js
            // how do I set loading (returned by the upper scope function) so I can use it in component.js?
        }

        return {
                otherVar,
                loading,
                setLoading
        };
    }
}

export default controller;
```

**component.js**

```
export default function component() {

    const { loading } = controller.postRender();

    return (
        <Wrapper onClick="setLoading(!loading)">
        </Wrapper>

   }
}
```

Comment: `useEffect ` can only be used in functional component or custom hooks. `postRender` is none of them. How could your code be working?

Comment: @TonyNguyen the postRender() you see there it's indeed called onRender() in my original code - I changed it assuming it was irrelevant since what  I see is `component.js` calling a method which returns some methods and some effects using state

Comment: As my understand React will raise issue right away when you define controller. Check the codesandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-practice-fetch-l8md0?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your ***component.js*** file as follows.

**File:** component.js

```
export default function component() {

    const { setLoading, loading } = controller.postRender();

    return (
        <Wrapper onClick={() => setLoading(!loading)}>
        </Wrapper>

   }
}
```

In your ***controller.js*** file change the loading variable as follows

update

```
const loading = useState(false);
```

to

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

And remove this function

```
const setLoading = (isLoaded) => {
            // this is called in component.js
            // how do I set loading (returned by the upper scope function) so I can use it in component.js?
}
```

Comment: but that doesn't update `loading` on controller.js which is my goal. is it supposed to?

Comment: I have updated my comment, by adding changes that you need to do in your controller.js file.

Answer (score 2):

First I would modify the **controller.js** and make it a proper custom hook.

Something like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const useDragon = () => {
  const [otherState, setOtherState] = useState(0);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOtherState(1);
  }, [setOtherState]);

  const changeLoading = () => {
    // assuming you want to toggle the loading
    setLoading(prevLoading => !prevLoading)
  };

  return {
    otherState,
    loading,
    changeLoading
  };
};

export default useDragon;
```

and in the component you can use it this way:

```
export default function component() {

    const { otherState, loading, changeLoading } = useDragon();

    return (
        <Wrapper onClick={changeLoading}>
        </Wrapper>

   }
}
```